# KnockoutJS Bind checkbox visibility to checkbox being checked OR having a certain value

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

So I have a checkbox, and I'm trying to implement the following logic to set the visibility:

If checkbox is checked OR the checkbox's value is below a specified number, set visible = true.

If the value exceeds the test value AND the checkbox is not checked, hide it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="visible: $data.Cost <= $root.itemLevel() - $root.totalEnchantLevelsUsed() || checked" />
```

I have tried several variations of getting 'checked', including changing 'checked' to $root.isChecked:

```
this.isChecked = ko.computed ( function (item) { 
  console.log('item', item); // PURELY TO TEST THE VALUE
}
```

But that is telling me that 'item' is undefined.  When I try to explicitly pass in $data, I get an error message about ko.computed and having to set 'write' access.

Is there not a relatively simple way to do this that I'm just overlooking?  Admittedly I'm not super familiar with knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something similar to what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/2aXrJ

Html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
    <label data-bind="visible: isAllowedInWorkflow">
        <input data-bind="value: val" type="checkbox" />
        This checkbox has value
        <span data-bind="text:val"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

jS:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    items: [createItem(10), createItem(20), createItem(30) ]
})

function createItem(val) {
    var  _item = {
         val: val
        ,isSelected: ko.observable(false)
    };
    _item.isAllowedInWorkflow = ko.computed(function() {
        //notice the order is importeant since you always want isSelected to be triggered for the 
        //computed to calculate its dependencies
        return !_item.isSelected() && val > 10; 
    });
    return _item;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to take that route as it means having to redo some of the code I've already implemented, and this is just a 'nice to have' feature.  But, I guess it is what it is.  Thanks.